# Small tweak to get this regex to get it to do what I want

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I wrote a coldfusion regex to match times of day in the source code of a page in which they appear scattered throughout the page like this:

```
<span>10.30</span> stuff <span>10.45-11.15</span> other stuff <span>17.00</span>
```

I want the matches to be "10.30" "10.45-11.15" and "17.00".
Instead, I am getting "10.30" "10.45" "11.15" and "17.00".

I have tried:

```
rematch("(\b[0-2][0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]\b)|(\b[0-2][0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]\.[0-5][0-9]\b)",mystring)
```

Thank you for correcting my error! Surely something to do with the little b's and the hyphen.

Comment: Change the order, do the hyphenated first. You also can do it all in one capture group, https://regex101.com/r/udlyAS/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the 'or', just make the range optional as follows:

```
\b[0-2]\d\.[0-5]\d(-[0-2]\d\.[0-5]\d)?\b
```

Here is the JavaScript equivalent snippet:

```js
var re = /\b[0-2]\d\.[0-5]\d(-[0-2]\d\.[0-5]\d)?\b/g;
var s = "<span>10.30</span> stuff <span>10.45-11.15</span> other stuff <span>17.00</span>";

console.log(s.match(re));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just make the part of the pattern that matches the second part of the range optional with the help of an optional non-capturing group `(?:...)?` and note that your regex also matches up to 29 hours that can also be corrected.

Use

```
\b(?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9])\.[0-5][0-9](?:-(?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9])\.[0-5][0-9])?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fs5g5Q/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9])` - either `2` followed with a digit from `0` to `3` or `0` / `1` followed with any digit (=hour)
- `\.` -  a literal dot
- `[0-5][0-9]` - a digit from `0` to `5` followed with any digit (=minute)
- `(?:-(?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9])\.[0-5][0-9])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a `-` and then the same pattern described above followed with...
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Comment: Th*nks, Wiktor. (I'm not supposed to write "thanks" in this box.) I tried your solution first and it worked perfectly. Gave Mr. Twoyears the green check mark because his solution is short and sweet!
But where am I supposed to say "thank you" if not in this box?

Comment: @user1781623 You can use the arrow next to the answer here. The `up vote` is kind of a way to thank a user. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow